# Create new row in database using the canjs example

Tags: mustache, canjs

I am attempting to extend this canjs example http://jsfiddle.net/xKc3H/367/
(it is the default todo's app).
I am wanting to add a new row.
I have made a button to open the editor, but when I try to save it, I get
a "undefined is not a function" on the "Todo.save()".

```
 <div id="content">
</div>
<script id='appMustache' type='text/mustache'>
<todos-app>
    <button can-click="select">Add todo</button>  
  <h2>Todays to-dos</h2>
  {{#selectedTodo}}
  <div id='editor'>
    <input type='text' can-value='description' can-change="saveTodo"/>
  </div>
  {{/selectedTodo}}
  <ul>
    {{#each todos}}
    <li>
      <input type='checkbox' can-value='complete'>
      <span class="description {{#if complete}}done{{/if}}" can-click='select'>{{description}}</span>
      <button can-click="destroy"></button>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
    </todos-app>
</script>
```

I have added a "create" method to my model.extend, but I am not getting that far...

```
// Here's where we get, save, and delete to-dos.
// (Yep, this is all we need to access the Todo
// REST endpoints!)
var Todo = can.Model.extend({
    findAll: 'GET /todos',
    findOne: 'GET /todos/{id}',
    update: 'PUT /todos/{id}',
    **create: 'PUT /todos/{id}'**,
    destroy: 'DELETE /todos/{id}'
}, {});

// For this example, we're not actually going out to
// a REST endpoint, so we'll use fixtures to emulate that.
// Fixtures help you test your application when you
// don't have access to your REST services.
var TODOS = [
    'Download CanJS',
    'Read the guides',
    'Build your app',
    'Become immortal',
    'Haircut @ 2pm'
];

var todoStore = can.fixture.make(TODOS.length, function(i) {
    return {
        id: i + 1,
        description: TODOS[i],
        done: false
    };
});

can.fixture({
    'GET /todos': todoStore.findAll,
    'GET /todos/{id}': todoStore.findOne,
    'PUT /todos/{id}': todoStore.update,
    **'PUT /todos/{id}': todoStore.create,**
    'DELETE /todos/{id}': todoStore.destroy
});

// Let's drag this out a bit.
can.fixture.delay = 500;

can.Component.extend({
  tag: "todos-app",
  scope: {
    selectedTodo: null,
    todos: new Todo.List({}),
    select: function(todo){
      this.attr('selectedTodo', todo);
    },
    saveTodo: function(todo) {
      console.log('in saveTodo')
      todo.save();
      this.removeAttr('selectedTodo');
    }
  }
})

// Start the application by rendering our template!
$("#content").html(can.view("appMustache", { }))
```

Comment: What does "Todo" look like?  If it's an instance, it should be lowercased `todo`.  In JavaScript, it's customary to only capitalize constructor function names.

Comment: you are correct Justin, I capitalized those to see if "Todo" == "todo"...   I have corrected the code snip.

Comment: Could you update the original fiddle to show the error?

Comment: I see the error when I run on my local machine (local webserver), not via jsfiddle...  the jsfiddle just stops at the todo.save() statement...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/xKc3H/635/

The problem is with calling "select" here:

```
<button can-click="select">Add todo</button>
```

When select is called, it will not be called with a new Todo instance as the first argument.  It will be called with the todos-app's scope.  So, I changed it to call a "createTodo" method that looks like:

```
createTodo: function(){
  var todo = new Todo();
  this.attr('selectedTodo', todo );  
  this.attr('todos').unshift(todo);
}
```

This creates a new Todo instance, marks it as being selected, and adds it to the list of todos.

Another version of this might check in saveTodo if the selectedTodo is in todos, if not, unshift the selectedTodo onto todos.